# List files based on files name

Tags: r

I have a folder that contains 2000 file of xls and xlsx extension whose name is somewhat related to the excel file city name (EX: DELHI123.xlsx, Delhi65.xls, DELhi456.xls, Mumbai989.xlsx, Indore123,Indore567 etc.)

I have another excel file having only one column that contains names of 900 files of the folder.

I want to keep only that 900 files whose name in present in the excel sheet and want to delete the remaing,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `file.remove`-function for that.

An example implementation:

```
allfiles <- list.files(pattern = '.xls')
to_remove <- allfiles[!(allfiles %in% my900names)]
file.remove(to_remove)
```

Comment: is my900names a data frame that contains the names of files??

Comment: @Subhashree it is the column of your dataframe that contains the 900 names, you could replace `my900names` with for example `df$my900names`

Comment: it worked! thank you so much